# I just turned my python script into an exe, when I open it, it closes immediately

Tags: python, selenium, exe

At the beginning of the script, there are a few lines of code that are supposed to be printed.  There are then a series of inputs.  After the inputs, the program is supposed to run and use selenium within Chrome.  This executes perfectly in the shell, but once I turned it into an executable, it closes immediately when I click to open it.  I understand that after all the inputs are input it should close immediately, but my executable shows me nothing and closes faster than I opened it.

Thanks for the help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: You'll need to add more information, such as how you turn it into an EXE

Comment: Execute the exe from a command prompt so you can see the output after it closes. To do so: hold shift, right click in the folder with your exe, click on "Open command window here", then type in yourprogram.exe and hit enter.